# Change in Google Earth Collada Support with Version 7.1

Tags: google-earth

I have an application that creates Collada Models in Google Earth that worked fine in version 7.0 but with 7.1 the colors stored in a 24bit PNG texture are no longer displayed. The model displays but no colors. I tried switching to a jpg (supposed to be allowed in Collada) but that didn't work either. Anyone know what the problem might be?

Additional: I just discovered that if you unzip the KMZ file my model will display with the colors from my texture. However if I rezip with a different zip program (7zip) the problem returns.

Answer (score 0):

Google has acknowledged that its a bug in 7.1:

"We can confirm the loss of textures in GE 7.1.1.1580 (beta) for images embedded in the kmz. If 7.1 is required, workarounds include reference to a network, web or local path outside the kmz (as you have found). We think this is a glitch in the beta, relating to extraction of the textures from a zip archive, and expect to see a fix in a later update.

For example, change the   in your  to access an alternate image outside of the kmz:

c:/test/sample.png
sample.png

When you Save Place As (*.kmz), GE 7.1 still copies the image into the zip archive and writes sample.png to doc.kml, which is a good sign.
-wxazygy"